# Centering navigation bar

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am having trouble centering my navigation bar, I have tried display:inline-block and then align center like most posts suggest but it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
<!--Navigation-->
<div class="band navigation">
    <nav class="container primary">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav.primary{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav.primary ul, nav.primary ul li {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav.primary select {
  display: none;
  width:  100%;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 21px 0;
}

nav.primary ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav.primary ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding:  0 14px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  background: ##999999;
}

nav.primary ul li a:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally got it:

```
nav.primary ul li {
display: inline;
float: left; <---
position: relative;
```

Remove the float: left;

Since the navigation is the full width of the containing div, there is no need to mess with floats, the list items will line up with just display: inline;

Comment: Wow great, thanks so much! It seems this added a small portion under the tabs though which is odd, ill keep working on it.EDIT: nevermind got it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried something else that works... It seems to work better than trying to build in something custom thus far in my experience with Skeleton... Although it produces a bit less pretty markup for the HTML, the rigidity of the final result works for me. Here is my code so that you can see what I did to achieve the desired effect:

`<div class="row">
      <div class="two columns offset-by-three">
        <a href="#" class="nav">Portfolio</a>
      </div>
      <div class="two columns">
        <a href="#" class="nav">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="two columns">
        <a href="#" class="nav">Contact</a>
      </div>
      </div>`

What you can see here is that the skeleton framework allows for the columns to operate naturally and restack at lower resolutions without any extra code. The only *tricky* part really is setting up the offset on the left most item.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `nav.primary ul {text-align: center;}` 
As well as keeping the left/right margins to auto, this worked for me when I was using the skeleton framework.

Comment: just tried this and it didnt work    .nav.primary ul{
 text-align: center;
 right:auto;
 left: auto;
}